# Keep canvas object in one place against changing size of the entire canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

l was wondering about the logic required in-order to position a canvas object, in this instance it is a image, in the bottom right corner of the canvas persistently. l essentially need help with the canvas object staying in one place without it moving up,down,left,right due to the resizable canvas.

l also have tested using event listeners to constantly update the position of the canvas object depending on the window size of the canvas but l believe it would end up becoming an inefficient solution.

To see it working, full screen/expand the code snippet and change your window size by double clicking your browser's tab or simply resize it, then you should be able to see it in action.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var the_button = document.getElementById("the_button");
var the_background = document.getElementById("the_background");

var button_imageX = 115;
var button_imageY = 85;

window.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(the_background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(the_button, button_imageX, button_imageY, 130, 75);
}

initialize();

function initialize() {
  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
  resizeCanvas();
}

function redraw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(the_background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(the_button, button_imageX, button_imageY, 130, 75);
}

function resizeCanvas() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  redraw();
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>


<img style="display: none;" id="the_button" src="https://i.imgur.com/wO7Wc2w.png" />

<img style="display: none;" id="the_background" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/hand-painted-watercolor-background-with-sky-clouds-shape_24972-1095.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg" />

</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible demo

Comment: @NisanthReddy l have added a window.onload function, this should provide you with the reproducible demo you wanted :D

Comment: Have posted a detailed answer. Check it out.

Comment: @NisanthReddy Ok, this logic makes sense- Thanks senior dev :D, so essentially l just have to ensure everything l do with canvas objects is 'relative' to the canvas. And again, Thanks for the detailed response! :D

Comment: That's correct. More specifically, relative to the top left point of your canvas. Glad to help. Do consider accepting the answer so that it may help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all about rectangle geometry.

Basically the culprit is this line that is present at 2 different places.

`ctx.drawImage(the_button, button_imageX, button_imageY, 130, 75);`

When you want the button to be a certain fixed position when you resize, you should provide fixed values as the 2nd and 3rd params for the `drawImage` function.

Change it to this,

`ctx.drawImage(the_button, button_imageX, canvas.height - button_imageY, 130, 75);`

The 2nd param `button_imageX` is already fixed.

But the 3rd param is the value of y from the `top of the canvas` where your button should be. Not from the bottom. You must be confused with cartesian coordinate system.

So if you want your button to be always a fixed position from bottom. you should canvas.height.

So `canvas.height - button_imageY` means that the top left point of your button will always be `button_imageY` pixels above the bottom of the canvas.

You might also want to consider the height of the button, so the new 3rd parameter will become `canvas.height - button_imageY - button_height`

Check the snippet for full code.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var the_button = document.getElementById("the_button");
var the_background = document.getElementById("the_background");

var button_imageX = 25;
var button_imageY = 25;

window.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(the_background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawButton();
}

initialize();


function initialize() {
  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
  resizeCanvas();
}

function drawButton() {
  ctx.drawImage(the_button, button_imageX, canvas.height - button_imageY - 75, 130, 75);
}

function redraw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(the_background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawButton();
}

function resizeCanvas() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  redraw();
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>


<img style="display: none;" id="the_button" src="https://i.imgur.com/wO7Wc2w.png" />

<img style="display: none;" id="the_background" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/hand-painted-watercolor-background-with-sky-clouds-shape_24972-1095.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg" />

</html>
```